# Kafka RoundRobinPartitioner Uneven Distribution in Kakfa 2.4+

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have encountered an issue where I found that Kafka is sending to messages only to the even numbered partitions.

After exploring, found that Kafka has this open bug reported wherein partition method gets called twice, leading to skipping odd partitions.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9965

There was PR raised during Oct 2021 and after that couldn't find any further update.

**Does anyone know if Kafka has fixed this issue and released any patch ? I am using Kakfa version 2.4.1.**

Please see the comment from the ticket

*RoundRobinPartitioner states that it will provide equal distribution of records across partitions. However with the enhancements made in KIP-480, it may not. In some cases, when a new batch is started, the partitioner may be called a second time for the same record:
https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.4/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.java#L909
https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.4/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.java#L934
Each time the partitioner is called, it increments a counter in RoundRobinPartitioner, so this can result in unequal distribution.*

**Code snippet**

```
package com.example.javakafka;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.Properties;

public class ProducerDemo {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProducerDemo.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String bootstrapServers = "127.0.0.1:9092";

        // create Producer properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty("partitioner.class", "com.example.javakafka.RoundRobinPartitionerNew");

        // create the producer
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);

        // create a producer record
        ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord ;

        int counter = 0;

        while(counter < 40) {

            // create a producer record
            producerRecord =
                    new ProducerRecord<>("demo-java-topic-10", "hello world");

            // send data - asynchronous
            producer.send(producerRecord);
            counter++;
        }

        // flush data - synchronous
        producer.flush();
        // flush and close producer
        producer.close();
    }
}
```

RoundRobinPartitionerNew Class - Same code as in Kafka API *org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RoundRobinPartitioner*

```
package com.example.javakafka;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Partitioner;
import org.apache.kafka.common.Cluster;
import org.apache.kafka.common.PartitionInfo;
import org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils;

public class RoundRobinPartitionerNew implements Partitioner {
    private final ConcurrentMap<String, AtomicInteger> topicCounterMap = new ConcurrentHashMap();

    public RoundRobinPartitionerNew() {
    }

    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs) {
    }

    public int partition(String topic, Object key, byte[] keyBytes, Object value, byte[] valueBytes, Cluster cluster) {
        List<PartitionInfo> partitions = cluster.partitionsForTopic(topic);
        int numPartitions = partitions.size();
        int nextValue = this.nextValue(topic);
        List<PartitionInfo> availablePartitions = cluster.availablePartitionsForTopic(topic);
        if (!availablePartitions.isEmpty()) {
            int part = Utils.toPositive(nextValue) % availablePartitions.size();
            return ((PartitionInfo)availablePartitions.get(part)).partition();
        } else {
            return Utils.toPositive(nextValue) % numPartitions;
        }
    }

    private int nextValue(String topic) {
        AtomicInteger counter = (AtomicInteger)this.topicCounterMap.computeIfAbsent(topic, (k) -> {
            return new AtomicInteger(0);
        });
        return counter.getAndIncrement();
    }

    public void close() {
    }
}
```

If I use version 1.0.0 and use the partitioner "org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.RoundRobinPartitionerNew"

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

it will properly distribute the messages as follows:

```
CreateTime:1673933856783    Partition:9 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:9 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:9 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:9 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856783    Partition:8 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:8 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:8 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:8 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856783    Partition:5 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:5 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:5 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:5 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856783    Partition:4 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:4 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:4 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:4 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:7 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:7 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:7 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:7 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:6 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:6 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:6 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:6 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856783    Partition:1 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:1 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:1 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:1 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856781    Partition:0 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:0 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:0 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:0 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:3 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:3 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:3 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:3 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856783    Partition:2 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:2 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:2 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933856784    Partition:2 null    hello world
```

If I use the version 2.4.1 onwards and use the same partitioner

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I get below where only even numbered partitions are assigned

```
CreateTime:1673933438685    Partition:8 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:8 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:8 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:8 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:8 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:8 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:8 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:8 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:4 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:4 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:4 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:4 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:4 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:4 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:4 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:4 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:6 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:6 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:6 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:6 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:6 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:6 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:6 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:6 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:0 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:0 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:0 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:0 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:0 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:0 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:0 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:0 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:2 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:2 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:2 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:2 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:2 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:2 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:2 null    hello world
CreateTime:1673933438688    Partition:2 null    hello world
```

Comment: Calling partition function on the same key would result in the exact same partition since it's a hash. Please show your producer code in a [mcve]. Also, just try upgrading and see if it's fixed. Your clients don't need to match the broker

Comment: I have updated the description with further details.

Comment: You've pointed at source code, sure. But show your actual producer application, proving that offsets are "only written to even partitions"

Comment: Yes updated with code snippets and results

Comment: Bumped into the same situation. I don't understand why KAFKA is ignoring this issue.